# Cast and get value datePickerDialog in Android Studio

Tags: android

Can datePickerDialog be cast like `EditText` ?  I can declare `EditText` like this

```
final EditText etName = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.etName);
```

and we can cast it into

```
String name = etName.getText().toString();
```

What about datePickerDialog ?

I've created **RegisterRequest.java** to put the value. i don't know what type to put because in mysql database, i've set the type as **datetime**.

```
public class RegisterRequest extends StringRequest{

    private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "http://localhost/takonami/Register.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public RegisterRequest(Date datetime, Response.Listener<String> listener){
        super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("datetime", "" +datetime);
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }
}
```

And in **RegisterActivity.java** . i've set the edit text named **"etDate"** n register button named **"bRegister"** . i already add pickerDialog inside onClick method.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v == etDate) {
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            // Display Selected date in textbox
                            etDate.setText(year + "-"
                                    + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth);
                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            dpd.show();
        }
```

but i don't know how to cast the **etDate** inside the bRegister listener since the type is not String,double,float or int. it **datetime** format . am i doing it wrong ?

```
bRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bRegister);
        bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    datePicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.etDate);
                    Integer dobYear = datePicker.getYear();
                    Integer dobMonth = datePicker.getMonth();
                    Integer dobDate = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
                    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(dobYear.toString()).append("-").append(dobMonth.toString()).append("-").append(dobDate.toString()).append(" 00:00:00");
                    String dobStr=sb.toString();

                    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                                Boolean success = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");
                                if (success) {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Register success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "failed success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    RegisterRequest registerRequest = new RegisterRequest(datePicker, responseListener);
                    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(RegisterActivity.this);
                    requestQueue.add(registerRequest);
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Required fields asterisk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

btw , here's my **Register.php** file

```
<?php
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "root", "takonami");

    $datetime     = $_POST['datetime'];

        global $connect, $datetime ;
        $statement = mysqli_prepare($connect, "INSERT INTO user (datetime) VALUES (?)");
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "i", $datetime);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
        mysqli_stmt_close($statement);     

    $response = array();


    echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combined all the answers and made a code snippet out of it.

Import datePicker on the top of your class:

```
import android.widget.DatePicker;
Inside your class declare the following variable:

private DatePicker dobPicker;
And here is the code to be done in button click event:

 dobPicker = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.dobPicker);
        Integer dobYear = dobPicker.getYear();
        Integer dobMonth = dobPicker.getMonth();
        Integer dobDate = dobPicker.getDayOfMonth();
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(dobYear.toString()).append("-").append(dobMonth.toString()).append("-").append(dobDate.toString()).append(" 00:00:00");
        String dobStr=sb.toString();
```

Where in R.id.dobPicker, dobPicker is your datePicker in the layout xml file. This gives you a string at the end, which could be stored or sent to the server.

Comment: can you check my coding above ? i'm stuck on declaring and casting it inside bRegister.onSetListener. since the type of datetime in database is datetime format . thanks.

Answer (score 0):

//on Button Click Event call this method

```
    private void datePicker(){
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    final  SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
                    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(activity, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();
                        newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                        // here code for store value in DB
                  String datTymValue = dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime());
                    }

                }, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                datePickerDialog.show();
        }
```

Comment: can you check my coding above to see what's wrong ? i've edit my question earlier . . thanks .

Comment: Apps stop working  . Error on RegisterActivity.java surely cause i dont know how to cast the value of datePicker . . If editText string no problem on that. . I've change stmt_bind_params to "s" . Still didnt work . . I've change the type of datetime to String in constructor . Same error. Apps crash when i hit bRegister button . .

Comment: there is no issue with datepicker. this code is fine. b by the way . what is RegisterRequest ?

Comment: Im using Volley . Basically im using StringRequest to add the values. So im separating the file. . RegisterRequest contain the constructor. . And i call back the RegisterRequest inside the bRegister button listener . .

Comment: Yeah . The code works fine when i choose the date . But it fails to store into the database. . . The value of the datepicker needs to be added inside bRegister listener . .

Comment: may be there is issue with RegisterRequest .

Comment: I think so too . I think Date datetime need to be change into Timestamp datetime first . But i'll give a try first ..